# Perl printing the rows beyond the first in a table

Tags: perl

Im currently new to perl....

So I have a table:

```
Name        Age    
Steven      18
Joe         19
Peter       20
```

and I want my script to print out the rows under 'Name' in the first column
so it will look like this when i run the script:

```
Steven    
Joe
Peter
```

my script looks like this atm:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;  
use warnings;

my $file=$ARGV[0];

my @array;
my $line;
my $row;

open (File, "< $file") or die "Input file: $!";

@array = <File>;

foreach $line (@array)
{
    my @array1 = split(/\s+/, "$line");
    my @row=split(/\s+/, "$array1[0]");

    print $row[1];
}
```

when i run it i cant seem to print out the string 'Steven' from my array.
can I have some guidance?

Comment: You did already split your line and stored it into `array1`. This variable is your row.

Comment: No need for the second `split` line. No need to quote variables, use `$line` and `$array1[0]`.  A good way to `split` on spaces is `split ' ', $line;` where `' '` is a special pattern for [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) (read the linked documentation page). Use the three-argument `open` (directly better), like so `open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";`

Answer (score 4):

Here's the [Modern Perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/) way to do that:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

while (<DATA>) {
    next if $. == 1;
    my ($name, $age) = split;
    say $name;
}

__DATA__
Name        Age
Steven      18
Joe         19
Peter       20
```

Notes:

- You generally want to avoid reading an entire file into memory if you can avoid it, and in this case, you can avoid it.
- We skip over the header row by using `$.`, which is [the current line number for the last filehandle accessed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24.).
- When arguments to [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) are omitted, it acts on `$_` and splits on `' '`, which removes leading whitespace before splitting and treats the pattern as `/\s+/`.
- [`say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) is just like `print`, except that it implicitly appends a newline. It's automatically enabled with a `use 5.010` or higher.

Answer (score 1):

One of these lines is redundant:

```
my @array1 = split(/\s+/, "$line");
my @row=split(/\s+/, "$array1[0]");
```

this works as desired:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file=$ARGV[0];
my @array;
my $line;
my $row;

@array = <DATA>;
my $isContent = 0;
foreach $line (@array)
{
    my @row = split(/\s+/, $line);
    next if not @row;
    next if not $isContent++;
    print "$row[0]\n";
}   

__DATA__

Name        Age
Steven      18
Joe         19
Peter       20
```